# Adding to 2D Array returning 'Index 0 out of bounds for length 0' error

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a string `currentBoard` that is `#######.x+.##..w.##....#######`. I'm trying to add each character in the string to a 2D-array so it will look like this:

```
######
#.x+.#
#..w.#
#....#
######
```

I can't figure out why the out of bounds error keeps coming up. I've tested to check that the values I use to determine the array size are valid, I've tested adding a value manually, like `gameboard[0][0] = '#';` which **doesn't work**. This is my first time working with multi-dimensional arrays so I must be doing something totally dumb. I just can't figure it out.

Here's the entire code block I'm working with:

```java
static char[][] gameBoard = new char[currentWidth][currentHeight];
public static void generateBoard() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentBoard.length(); i++) {
        char z = currentBoard.charAt(i);
        gameBoard[x][y] = z;
        if (y == currentHeight) {
            y = 0;
        }
        if ((i + 1) % currentWidth == 0) {
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
}
```

`currentHeight` is 5, `currentWidth` is 6.

Comment: Something to keep in mind, `int[][] array` is an "array of arrays" in concept, meaning if you refer to `array[0]`, you'd get an `int[]` back, and `array[0][0]` would return `(array[0]) [0]` or the first `int` element of that first `int[]` array. In practice these are actually similar to a single dimensional array, but that's for later on

Comment: Were currentHeight and currentWidth given  values before you defined the board array?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be greatly simplified by making the observation that the x-coordinate will be  the remainder of dividing `i` by `currentWidth` and the y-coordinate will be the quotient of `i` divided by the `currentWidth`, rounded down.

```java
public static void generateBoard() {
    for (int i = 0, len = currentBoard.length(); i < len; i++) {
        char z = currentBoard.charAt(i);
        final int x = i % currentWidth;
        final int y = i / currentWidth;
        gameBoard[x][y] = z;
    }
}
```

See the above code in action [here](https://ideone.com/buq1oc).

Comment: Unfortunately, this still returns the same out of bounds error.

Comment: there's a problem that the board is declared as `new char[currentWidth][currentHeight];` instead of `new char[currentHeight][currentWidth];`

Comment: @Amelia Does the sample code I provided work for you?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Either way can work, provided the loop is written correctly.

Comment: Yes, it won't have ArrayOutOfBoundsException but the result will be printed differently :)

Comment: @AlexRudenko That also depends on how you write the loop to print the result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the width and height in the declaration of the board have to be switched:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currentBoard = "#######.x+.##..w.##....#######";
    char[][] board = new char[5][6];
    for (int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0; i < currentBoard.length(); i++) {
        board[y][x] = currentBoard.charAt(i);
        x++;
        if (x == board[y].length) {
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
    }

    for (char[] row : board) {
        System.out.println(new String(row));
    }
}
```

prints as expected:

```
######
#.x+.#
#..w.#
#....#
######
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to set static fields for your array parameters, but the array is already created at the point you're updating them. Take for example:

```
static int height; // == 0!
static int width; // == 0!
static char[][] gameBoard = new char[currentWidth][currentHeight];

public static void main(String... args) {
    height = 5;
    width = 6;
    //but the gameboard is already made
    generateBoard();
}

public static void generateBoard() {
    //...
    //gameboard is not valid, 
}
```

In general, avoid misusing static for reasons like above. One solution to this problem would be to have a class which encapsulates your game board, and takes the width/height as arguments.